# Difference between a mixture of distributions and a convolution. Intuition

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

From what I could gather

- Mixture: if $X_i\sim^{iid} f_i$, then W is a mixture with $f_W =\sum \frac{f_i}{n}$. This definition could also be for the CDF instead of the density.
- Convolution: To make it simpler, lets assume if $X_i\sim^{iid} N(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)$, then $W=X_1+X_2\sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2)$. We could write this in terms of densities.

What I don't get is the practical intuition for these definitions.

For example: We have two machines, each producing observations $X_i\sim f_i$.

If there's probability $p$ that machine 1 is chosen, how do we model our final observation $W$? As a convolution or a mixture? And what changes should we do to our problem/situation to model it as the other possibility?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: Could convolution, as written above be also used for more than two random variables and still maintain the interpretation as $W=\sum X_i$?

Comment: Indeed, convolution corresponds to adding (two or more) independent random variables while mixture corresponds to choosing one of them with given probabilities, independently of their value. In formulas, the result of the operation is $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ in the former case and $X_N$ where $N$ is independent of $(X_k)$ and has values in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ in the latter case.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your comment

Comment: In both cases you are adding stuff together. A mixture of probabilities add up the probabilities while in convolution you actually sum two or more random variables. They are therefore very different. In your example, for instance, if the densities are assumed Gaussian, then the sum of random variables also has a Gaussian density. However, the mixture density looks like some overlapped Gaussian functions (it is not Gaussian!).